# EC probe for hydroponics; physical design considerations

Tags: design, measurement, voltage-measurement, electrode

I want to build a simple EC-meter with two electrodes for a hydroponics project. A naive solution would just have the (copper plate) electrodes hanging into the water, but then the active electrode surface area (\$A\$ in calculations like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductivity_%28electrolytic%29)) becomes dependent on the water surface level. My friend suggested a 3D-printed sleeve to overcome the problem, like this:

[image: Probe with sleeve]

The idea is that only the bits of copper sticking out at the bottom will act as electrodes, the sleeve letting us submerge them to sufficient depth that surface level variation is not a problem. However, I am a bit worried about water migrating up into the sleeve, possibly affecting the effective electrode area, or causing other problems.

So, is this a good design? If not, do you have better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a powercord outlet - it has a standartized size and is easy to find.

This link have an example and the code: https://hackaday.io/project/7008-fly-wars-a-hackers-solution-to-world-hunger/log/24646-three-dollar-ec-ppm-meter-arduino

Comment: I have seen that article, but I don't think it addresses the problem. To avoid the water surface level issue I would have to submerge the plastic plug, and then I would still worry that water might migrate into the cord.

Comment: Water leakage risk in an plastic injected outlet seems to be lower than in a 3d printed material

Comment: That is true, but it might still not be good enough. What I really want to know is whether or not the concept itself is flawed, and if water seeping into the sleeve will affect the readings.

Comment: As someone who suffers from the same tendencies, I would say that at some point one must stop wondering and start experimenting!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a good design, but some considerations are needed. Select the appropriate 3D-printing filament; for example, natural color PETG is recommended but PLA is not for water resistance (other options exist).

There should be some barrier to prevent water wicking into the 3D printed part. This could be an O-ring if sold-metal conductor were circular. With rectangular metal bar, recommend a urethane-based potting material like MG Chemicals 832HD-25ML (other options available).

In water submerged setting, copper will corrode easily depending on solutes and pH. I think stainless steel 316 will be a better choice. Also recommend a shroud around conductive metal to avoid it contacting things and cause measurement error.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Since posting this we have reconsidered, and the current plan is to wrap each electrode in [EPR self-amalgamating tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-amalgamating_tape), exposing only the top and bottom (as in the original design). Then we can sandwich them with a separator of any old material to get the desired separation. Steel as substitute for copper is an interesting idea. Will not the lower conductivity be a problem?